# Is there an equivalent of javascript Math.min() in bash/bc etc.?

Tags: bash, osx, bc

I need to convert some javascript calculations to bash, and I am wondering if there is an equivalent function of javascript `Math.min()` in bash, bc or any other calculator in the shell?

Comment: How will the data be presented? Shell array? Separate variables ? A string - one with newline separators?

Comment: No, there is no pre-defined minimum. But you should read http://stackoverflow.com/q/21452752/2350426

Answer (score 2):

With POSIX shell:

```
min() {
  min=$1
  shift
  for arg do
    min=$((arg<min?arg:min))
  done
  printf '%s\n' "$min"
}
```

All shells but `zsh`, `ksh` and `yash` do not support float numbers.

With POSIX toolchest:

```
min() {
  awk 'BEGIN {
    min = ARGV[1]
    for(i = 2; i < ARGC; i++)
      min = ARGV[i] < min ? ARGV[i] : min
    print min
  }' "$@"
}
```

And if you have `perl`:

```
min() {
  perl -MList::Util=min -le 'print min @ARGV' "$@"
}
```

or `perl6`:

```
min() {
  perl6 -e '@*ARGS.min.say' "$@"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Push your data to a file, then sort them up and get the first line.

```
#/bin/sh

echo $VAR1 > $FILE
echo $VAR2 >> $FILE
echo $VAR3 >> $FILE 

RET=$(sort -n $FILE | sort -n)
```

Comment: We expect answers to be more comprehensive here. Please [edit] your answer and explain how exactly the OP can do what you suggest. As it stands, this is a comment, not an answer.